# Python 3.7 install fails with anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I try to install python 3.7 for anaconda with the following command:

```
conda install -c anaconda python=3.7
```

And its showing the following failure message:

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - _license -> python=3.6
  - python=3.7
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following page provides a solution: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/9686

and could solve it by creating a new virtual environment with the following command and without the default packages:

```
conda create -n python37 python=3.7 --no-default-packages
```